# Realtek RTL8723BE Wifi Disconnecting After few minutes

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have **Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN**. I am successfully connected to a network and doing works for minutes. Suddenly I noticed after few minutes that not a single page is opening, showing resolving host or something like that, but I am still connected to the network. But when I am disconnecting and reconnecting again to the same network it works fine again for few minutes and the same issue again and again, but my LAN connection is stable. **Please Help me out**.

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 32 bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi problem on Lenovo z50-70 with Realtek RTL8723BE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627903/wi-fi-problem-on-lenovo-z50-70-with-realtek-rtl8723be)

Comment: possible duplicate of [rtl8723ae unstable on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/629679/rtl8723ae-unstable-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-8723be-wireless-card-to-work

Answer (score 1):

Sayan Dutta, I also faced the same problem. But i manage to solve this by adding a file in system folder. Process is given below.

1. Download the following file from Dropbox and unzip the zip file.
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhk02dxj1vdei6d/rtl8723be.zip?dl=0
2. Then open the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and run following command

> gksudo nautilus

hit Enter and give the password.

3. Then a window will appear, then navigate to "/etc/modprobe.d"
4. Copy the extracted file and paste in the folder.

Then you have to restart the system and then your problem will be solved.

Comment: It is a config for the old driver. It does not help well.

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver this way. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot

Comment: After install this I was able to log in, the screen becomes black and then again it ask me for the password

Comment: How is it related with the question and the answer? Please ask a separate question with your problem.

Comment: It is a problem that it came up after applying or installing the driver