# Lost wireless connectivity after suspend on Lenovo Z5070

Tags: drivers, wireless, suspend

I have Lenovo z5070 with Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed.

I was downloading something on my laptop, and I left it to sleep. When the system woke up the wireless was gone. There was no option for enabling or disabling Wi-Fi.

The problem persisted after reboot.

There is no access point in the access point list and there is no icon that I can use to enable and disable Wi-Fi with. Actually there is no trace of anything related to wireless.

I ran the `iwconfig` command and the output was:

```
eth0       no wireless extension
```

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor co. Ld. RTL8723BE PCIe 
Wireles Network Adapter [10ec:b736]
        subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108m [GeForce 840M] [10de:1341] (rev a2)
```

I've tried to install `rtlwifi_new` again and `sudo make install` failed:

[image: screenshot of terminal with output - no rule to make target]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you previously installed a driver form source using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/627925/167850), you will need to re-install it after each kernel upgrade. That may be the case.

If you did not remove sources, then run

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

If you DID remove the sources, then download [driver as zip.](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git)

Extract it to your home folder and install by

```
cd rtlwifi_new-master
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot

Also after sleep mode sometimes Network Manager is stuck. You can restart it using

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: yes I've installed that driver but I didn't upgrade my kernel but I will check the command

Comment: You could install normal updates and kernel could be updated too. You do not need to do anything special to upgrade kernel.

Comment: how can I remove the source?

Comment: I meant source of Realtek driver. It is in `rtlwifi_new` folder.  Do not delete it.

Comment: I have no net so I can't download rtlwifi_new again

Comment: Then do it. The driver is not installed not. Do "git clone ....". It will download it.

Comment: I can't install driver again and I put the result in the main question

Comment: I edited the question for your case.

Comment: The problem still goes on without any success

Comment: Maybe you pressed a button like Fn+F2 and turned off wireless.

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the answer [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2040240).

I just ran the following command and Wi-Fi came back suddenly

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Comment: The second command does nothing, only gives output. Maybe it makes sense to download driver source, while you can.

Comment: yes you right . there were some commands that the person who suggest this commands says runs after this commands but I didn't run them and nothing get worse.