# rtl8723ae unstable on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have searched through the internet and in AskUbuntu, but I could not find a working solution for my little problem.

The RTL8723ae WLAN is behaving strangely on Ubuntu 14.04 and drops the WLAN connection constantly. I am using the notebook MSI GE40 and have already seen on the web that there are other people having the same problem but there was no permanent solution. The problem did not exists on the original Windows 8 on the device and the router is a TP-Link, which I can control (channel change and so on, I use WPA2-PSK WLAN security).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install a better driver this way:

```
sudo apt-get install -y git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

**Note** You will need to reinstall the driver after each kernel upgrade.

**Update** I made a DKMS version of same driver. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

If you are on Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04, I recommend to upgrade linux-firmware from same ppa.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware.
```

In this case the driver will be automatically rebuilt after kernel upgrades.

***In case you install from PPA, you do not need to install from git***

Comment: Seems to work and be far more stable, but somehow a bit slower internet connection. Thank you! Any tips to check/fix the speed? (20Mbit on speedtest before unstable and 4Mbit stable after the drivers)

Comment: I can't help with the speed. You can ask Larry directly at github. He develops this driver. Link is same as you downloaded it from. The is "issues" button there.

Comment: It still drops in between. Should I change some configuration settings (http://askubuntu.com/a/775483/417607). Using the latest code from the github repo.