# Wifi not working on Realtek rtl8723be wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, 16.04

I am using kubuntu 16.04 on this [PC](http://www.hpshopping.in/HP_Pavilion_Notebook_-_15-ab549tx)
.

The problem that I am facing is:

**Wifi issue:**
It doesn't discover wifi at times and keeps getting disconnected randomly.
Also, when I am connected to a WiFi works very slow. But things go smooth 
when I boot into windows.
Information about wireless card:

```
abhishek@hp:~$ sudo lshw | grep wireless
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Information about hardware:

```
$ lspci |grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

abhishek@hp:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N
```

dmesg output related to issue:

```
[ 4288.272924] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
[ 4288.272935] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00000000
[ 4288.272943] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
[ 4297.800384] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 4297.800424] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 1355 at /build/linux-UbQGH5/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_uncore.c:649 __unclaimed_reg_debug+0x80/0x90 [i915_bpo]()
[ 4297.800427] Unclaimed register detected after reading register 0x65f10
[ 4297.800428] Modules linked in: nvram msr cmac rfcomm drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm bbswitch(OE) bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(POE) arc4 rtl8723be(OE) btcoexist(OE) rtl_pci(OE) rtlwifi(OE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media mac80211 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_core hp_wmi sparse_keymap rtsx_pci_ms memstick snd_compress ac97_bus btusb snd_pcm_dmaengine btrtl dw_dmac_core btbcm snd_hda_intel btintel snd_hda_codec bluetooth irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd
[ 4297.800463]  joydev input_leds serio_raw wmi hp_accel lis3lv02d snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event input_polldev hp_wireless snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd mei_me mei soundcore shpchp tpm_crb int3403_thermal processor_thermal_device int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc nvidia_drm(POE) i915_bpo nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse r8169 rtsx_pci mii drm ahci libahci video fjes
[ 4297.800491] CPU: 3 PID: 1355 Comm: alsa-sink-ALC32 Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 4297.800492] Hardware name: HP HP Pavilion Notebook/80A4, BIOS F.78 03/07/2016
[ 4297.800494]  0000000000000086 00000000b30b4625 ffff880276dd7780 ffffffff813e9c53
[ 4297.800496]  ffff880276dd77c8 ffffffffc0cea888 ffff880276dd77b8 ffffffff81080fb2
[ 4297.800498]  0000000000000000 0000000000000001 0000000000065f10 ffff88026f890080
[ 4297.800500] Call Trace:
[ 4297.800506]  [<ffffffff813e9c53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[ 4297.800509]  [<ffffffff81080fb2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[ 4297.800511]  [<ffffffff8108104c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[ 4297.800515]  [<ffffffff816f7588>] ? pci_conf1_write+0xb8/0xf0
[ 4297.800534]  [<ffffffffc0c5aac0>] __unclaimed_reg_debug+0x80/0x90 [i915_bpo]
[ 4297.800550]  [<ffffffffc0c609ae>] gen9_read32+0x35e/0x390 [i915_bpo]
[ 4297.800567]  [<ffffffffc0c66bb9>] i915_audio_component_codec_wake_override+0x39/0xb0 [i915_bpo]
[ 4297.800573]  [<ffffffffc0e839cf>] snd_hdac_set_codec_wakeup+0x3f/0xa0 [snd_hda_core]
[ 4297.800575]  [<ffffffffc0e970c7>] azx_runtime_resume+0x187/0x1b0 [snd_hda_intel]
[ 4297.800579]  [<ffffffff8143987b>] pci_pm_runtime_resume+0x7b/0xa0
[ 4297.800581]  [<ffffffff81556b23>] __rpm_callback+0x33/0x70
[ 4297.800584]  [<ffffffff81439800>] ? pci_restore_standard_config+0x40/0x40
[ 4297.800586]  [<ffffffff81556b84>] rpm_callback+0x24/0x80
[ 4297.800588]  [<ffffffff81439800>] ? pci_restore_standard_config+
```

**When I have tried so far:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi   
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

The first solution from [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-trusty-realtek.html). Didn't try the second one because I will have to recompile with each kernel update
then.

I tried make install from this https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi, could you check if this file exists;  `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` ?

Comment: @ankit7540 `abhishek@hp:~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`
`abhishek@hp:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N`

Comment: try this;  `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

This makes changes to the file mentioned for network adapter (power settings and antenna selection). After this change, reboot and check wifi connection.

Comment: @ankit7540 Now, it can discover the wifi-networks. And internet connection worked for `some` time after rebooting and then again stopped working.

Comment: @ Abhishek Bhatia -    Check with `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`   for selecting the antenna 1 and try. You have to reboot again.

Comment: @ankit7540 same as before, works for sometime. Then doesn't.

Comment: oh, weird. could you give the output of `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep signal`  This is for checking the signal strength.

Comment: @ankit7540 I rebooted a few times and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy that it works, however I suggest you to run it continuously  for some time and try downloading etc.. (Just make sure it is really solved !)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40101/discussion-between-ankit7540-and-abhishek-bhatia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is an ongoing problem and the following is more like a temporary answer.

**Step 1.** Add repository for the latest driver (maintained by **lwfinger on GitHub**) and install it.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware`

If you cannot install the driver then, disable secure boot from BIOS ( some notebooks have had this issue).

Your wifi-adapter should be working now (though maybe having weak signal or disconnects after some time).

**Step 2**. Edit the configuration file for the new driver for specific antenna selection and power management,

--**First** make a backup.

`sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf   /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.old.conf`

then,

`echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

**Step 3.** reboot

Your wifi-adapter should be working better now. It is suggested to test wireless connection under load for some time. User may test with `ant_sel=1`  or removing this parameter to ascertain best working condition. With every change reboot is needed.

More information: With future kernel update, no additional configuration is needed since `linux-firmware` is also installed.

Referring solutions : [Another issue with rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629679/rtl8723ae-unstable-on-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

Driver development by lwfinger on GitHub: [rtl8723be driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/master/rtl8723be)  Follow this for future updates.

Comment: If I turn off the wifi and turn it back on. It doesn't work, i.e. it can't detect any the wifis nearby. Only a reboot fixes it back. Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution for hours now always finding one that suggests installing the driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/ which **no longer exists**.

Turns out you no longer need that driver as it is part of the kernel now. But you might run into a **terrible signal strength** issue I was experiencing myself on my laptop.

The only thing that needed to be done was to execute this in a terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249902/realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-upgrading-to-5-4-0-37). Hope this helps someone running into the same problem.