# Wifi is not working. I have a laptp Hp with RTL8723BE. It says *-network UNCLAIMED

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, realtek, rtl8723be

I have updated the Ubuntu version to 16.04. Also I've tried a bunch of different solutions as those answering these questions for example:

[lenovo e540 RTL8723be wifi not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517772/lenovo-e540-rtl8723be-wifi-not-working][0])

[Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04][2])

[Wifi not working on Realtek rtl8723be wifi adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772180/wifi-not-working-on-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-adapter][3])

And none of them has worked. Please, if someone can help I'll appreciate it a lot.

The network command  `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: enp8s0
   version: 07
   serial: 3c:a8:2a:7b:fb:8c
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.47 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:41 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2600000-b2600fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2503fff
```

The `lspci | grep -i network` command :

```
09:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: I would think the rtlwifi-new-dkms would work perfectly. What didn't work as expected?

Comment: This is probably the Secure Boot issue. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @chili555 when I try the `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be`. Is says "Required key not available":
`mark@mark-HP-14-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available`

Comment: @Pilot6 is quite correct! Disable secure boot and it will likely be fixed.

Comment: @pilot6 yes the Disable secure boot worked! Now I'll try the rtlwifi-new-dkms.

Comment: @Mark It is installed already. I mean `rtlwifi-new-dkms`.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you. Yes probably it was, but I did the process again. Now the problem is I don't see the networks.

Comment: You probably installed a driver form other source. Remove `rtlwifi-new-dkms`.

Comment: @Pilot6 as the first part of the problem is solved, I have asked another question more specifically for the WiFi networks that are not appearing: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/802113/i-cant-see-wifi-networks-i-have-realtek-wireless-card-model-rtl8723be). Thank you very much.

Answer (score -3):

Try this in the terminal:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

then type:

```
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
```

then:

```
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: His driver is not `ath9k` as he hasn't an Atheros wireless device.

Comment: It's right, is a realtek wireless device.