# I can't see Wifi networks. I have realtek wireless card, model: RTL8723BE

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, rtl8723be

I upgraded Ubuntu from 15.04 to 16.04.

I have tried reinstalling `rtlwifi-new-dkms`

[Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Also, **I disabled Secure Boot in BIOS**, which help reactivating the wireless card. But I still can't see the available WiFi networks:

[No WiFi networks appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMmzV.jpg)

For the command `sudo lshw -C network` I get

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:7b:fb:8c
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.47 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2600000-b2600fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: c4:8e:8f:c4:58:e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2503fff
```

*Please if someone can help.*

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I did that 2 days ago. Now it turns on but I see no networks as the Image I link.

Comment: @chili555 Hi, maybe you know how can I deal with this now? Disabling the secure boot was part of it.

Comment: Should I restart my Ubuntu?

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it

Comment: @SteveRoome what do you recomend me to do?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
rock.new_btcoex
```

drivers if you find

```
rtlwifi_new
```

doesn't work.

same problem i've answered read datail instructions [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813172/problems-with-realtek-8723be/814515#814515)

tested and works on both Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18.
Good Luck!.