# Problems with Realtek 8723BE

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, rtl8723be

Just bought a new Lenovo Ideapad 100 14IBD, was having Wifi problems, lspci told me that the wifi card (RTL8723BE) was the same as my 2nd laptop (old one), so as usual I did what [this answer stated](https://askubuntu.com/a/635629/495496), only, it didnt work this time around. Wifi drops after 20 mins of connectivity (approximately),

rfkill list output

```
eragera@Gaurav-Linux:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

How do I make wifi be stable?

Comment: I think the problem is with Secure Boot enabled. Now 3rd party modules can't be loaded.

Comment: Secure Boot is off, turned it off first thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. download this Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless driver (rock.new_btcoex) from github [rock.new_btcoex](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/rock.new_btcoex.zip)
2. install

```
cd rock.new_btcoex
make
sudo make install
```

3. Check ant sel

```
modinfo -p rtl8723be
```

4. Tes ant sel

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1 (or) sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|level'
```

now you should find wifi signal on ant sel (1 or 2)

5. make this: depend on which ant sel that works

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
(or)
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

**[source](http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/05/install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-linuxmint.html)**

Read source for detail instructions, i found this work on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Im currently using the same exact driver, as stated by the answer linked in my question.