# Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter not working in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10, realtek-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a [Hp Envy Laptop](http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04863397) and facing problem with wifi connectivity. The wifi signal is very poor and sitting just next to the wifi router also causes disconnects and weak signal which also seems to drain my battery faster. Some other solution mentions of using proprietary driver for Realtek in the Addition Drivers window but I can't see it being listed there:-

[image: Additional Drivers]

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

**EDIT 1**

After followinf @Pilot6 's answer, the signal level dropped after few minutes. The following is output of running `watch -n1 iwconfig` sitting approx. 4 feet away from the router. The connection works when *Link Quality* is 40+/70.

[image]

Comment: Check this question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/772180/wifi-not-working-on-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-adapter/775483#775483

Comment: You probably need to set `ant_sel=2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

and reboot.

If it does not work, try with `ant_sel=2`

This will set the correct antenna and should fix the poor signal issue.

Comment: It worked momentarily and then got again disconnected. Please see updated question.

Comment: Try it with `ant_sel=1`. If nothing works, install drivers from git.

Comment: '1' worked finally.

Comment: The problem is that linux drivers can't detect which antenna is attached in 1 antenna configuration. We have to guess it.