# WiFi (rtl8723be driver) is gone in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek-wireless

When I tried to use wifi in my hp laptop after sleep, it was showing netwoks but was not connecting to any of them. So I rebooted the system hoping that problem will be fixed. But it got worse. Now wifi option is gone from settings and panel. I tried to disable secure boot but it didn't help. I tried to install driver shown in [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772180/wifi-not-working-on-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-adapter). But it didn't work either in 20.04. My kernel version is 5.4.0-33-generic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `sudo lshw -class network` will show which network interfaces were found. `find /lib -name rtl8723\*` will show which relevant drivers are available. `sudo modprobe rtl8723be` and `dmesg | egrep -i 'rtl|real|net|eth|wifi|error|fail'` may provide information. If you have a wired connection you could add the output of those commands to the original question.

Comment: are you trying to change antena selection in file /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/12/20/how-to-install-realtek-wifi-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-lts/). It solved my problem. Now my wifi is working.