# realtek rtl8723be wifi drivers not working after upgrading to 5.4.0-37

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, realtek

I have a system running on Ubuntu 20.04, I installed updates provided by Ubuntu. Seems it updated Linux kernel from `5.4.0-33` to `5.4.0-37`. After installing the updates, my wifi stopped working, I do not see any entries in the Wifi panel.

I tried to re-install lwfinger's driver again

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git -b rtw88
cd rtlwifi_new/
make
sudo make install
```

but build failed with the below error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic/build M=/home/xyz/script/rtl_kernel5/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 10 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic'
Making backups
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtwpci not found.
make: *** [Makefile:84: install] Error 1
```

I could see somebody has raised an issue on issue-tracker https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/479

Am I missing anything here?

As per [Lwfinger's Readme](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/blob/master/README.md):

> If you are running a kernel newer than 5.0, use the drivers built into your kernel. That is a lot less work.

I tried to install drivers to the kernel module:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

installed completed successfully, but the wifi panel still shows no entires. How can I fix this issue?

[EDIT] Adding some more info suggested in comments"

```
govi@falcon:~$ dkms status
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.4.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.6, 5.4.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.6, 5.4.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

govi@falcon:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Sanji2 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

dmseg output:

```
govi@jarvis:~$ dmesg | grep rtl
[   19.219998] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[   19.222073] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   19.222395] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   19.255565] rtl8723be 0000:03:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   24.711501] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   24.820548] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   24.820567] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status` command.

Comment: Also please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

Comment: @Pilot6 output added

Comment: All looks good here. Please add `dmesg | grep rtl` then.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated

Comment: This also looks good. Wi-Fi should be working.

Comment: @Pilot6 I checked one more time. I can connect to the wifi but I have stay very close to the outer. it's showing weak signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

and reboot. That should fix the bad signal.

Comment: worked. But which module is loaded in my case, the one which comes with Kernel or lwinger's? and as `sudo make install` is not working, how shall I fix it if I doesn't work after next Ubuntu updates?

Comment: It must be the kernel one. You can check by `modinfo rtl8723be`

Comment: seems to be. Does that mean I don't need to reinstall module after updates? I am using lwinger's drivers from last 2 years, every time I update the system I have to  install the drivers.

Comment: You can remove them completely. You had to re-install them each time, because you used a wrong way to install.