# Slow wifi ubuntu 16.04 in ultrabook

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, internet, connection

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto an LG laptop. Everything is working fine except the wireless connection. When I'm closer to the router, the connection is fast, but in my room the wireless is very slowly.

In Windows, I don't have this problem, but I don't want to use that system anymore.

Here is some output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)`
```

I tried the driver suggested on [the "rtl8723ae unstable on Ubuntu 14.04" question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629679/rtl8723ae-unstable-on-ubuntu-14-04), but unfortunately there was no improvement with that driver, the pages are slow to load, and the download rate is 200 – 300kbps (in Windows it was 1.0 – 1.1Mbps).

Is there any other alternative for this wireless

```
    01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: @Pilot6 I can install that driver too?

Comment: Yes, why not? But for 16.04 you may need to disablr Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 Unfortunately no improvement with this driver, the pages are slow to load, and the download rate is 200 ~ 300kbps in windows it was 1.0 ~ 1.1mbps

Comment: To add multiple-line output, please select the text and press the `{}` button. `\`` is only for one line of output at most.

Comment: Why don't you try with an older driver? You need to **downgrade** the driver. I'm not an expert on this so I cannot help you do that. Alternatively, you can create an Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD and test it there (selecting "Try ubuntu without installing").

Comment: Please, specify exact hardware in your question.

Comment: Sometimes, with obsolete routers, I disabling IPv6 helps a lot. Don't know if that's your case.